# How to compress 2D animation for apk build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, animation

I develop a mobile game for Android.
I have simple 2D animation by changing sprites one after another with Unity animator.
The sprites are located in one big picture and are slices of the picture.
I noticed when I add animation, the build size increases.
Is there a good way to reduce / compress animation in build apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on your visual style. You can try different texture compressions but not each of them can be applied to every texture without visible artifacts.

You can change compression in the texture import settings for every platform and check the result in the preview section of the inspector (perhaps, you will need to change the target platform in the editor first to be able to see the result).

Anyway, frame animations are not very commonly used. Exactly because of the increase in the build size. Especially if you have a lot of big frames. Complex 2d animations can be created using tools like [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/).

Here is a simple example of compressions and result size. The same picture, different compressions:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know about compression format, I use it. I've understood that I can't compress animation directly. 
You said about `Spine`, this is an engine, based on bone animation, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is used for 2d bone animation.